# HOw to use SelectedValuePath to get the ID

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to Get the Database ID of the item selectd in the Combo box in silverlight either by using SelectedValuePath or by any other way.
Please suggest.

Comment: waiting for a reply from this site is just a big waste of time.Here Concerned people are more interested in Text,Alignment and Proper texting of the Posted question rather than replying to the Query of Posters

Comment: What you are actually seeing is the pattern of not bothering to respond to new users (who do not themselves bother to answer questions). Users want feedback in return (which new users can't give). Shame, but it does pass once you get beyond 15 points.

Comment: I would suggest this question could do with some actual Xaml so we can see what you are already trying.

Comment: I have created an Operation Contract with the Name getStateID thru this im fetching my StateId from Database.
How can i access that single variable returning the value of StateId from getStateId Operation Contract from my form.xaml.cs code.
var services = new ServiceReference1.AlumniServiceClient();
This is how i have created object for Service Client.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML you must to write de name your Id in the combobox:

```
SelectedValuePath="ID"
```

where "ID" is the name of your field.

To get the selected value in c#:

```
int id=(int)myComboBox.SelectedValue;
```